# FatalErrorException Compile Error: Declaration of App\Controller\DefaultController::forward

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I tried to use the forward methode like this :

```
class DefaultController extends AbstractController{  // ligne 15

//some code ...

 /**
     * @Route("/forwarding", name="forwarding")
     */
    public function forward(){

        $response=  $this->forward(
            'App\Controller\DefaultController::resultfoorward',
            array('param'=> 1)
        );
        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/resultatForwarding/{param?}", name="resultfoorward")
     */

    // il faut écrire le parametre entre parenthèses pour pouvoir l'afficher
    public function resultfoorward($param){

        exit('Voila la page à qui j\'a forwardé et voil son param' .$param);
    }
```

But it didn't work. it gives me the following error :

> FatalErrorException
>   Compile Error: Declaration of App\Controller\DefaultController::forward() must be compatible with Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController::forward(string $controller, array $path = Array, array $query = Array): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
>
> in DefaultController.php line 15

I verified the syntaxe and  it seems to be correct.

Comment: please for the love of god or whatever is holy to you, call your controller actions `[something]Action` ... forwardAction for example. since you extend the AbstractController, whose function `forward` you call, you try to "override" the function with your action `forward` which must have the same function signature (as the error message tells you). then, to top this all off, you call forward inside forward ... so recursion.

Answer (score 2):

You are redeclaring the `forward()` method that is already defined in `AbstractController` or more specifically in `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerTrait`.

You also call `forward()` inside itself, which can lead to infinite recursion.

You need to rename the `forward` method, ideally to `forwardAction()` and `resultfoorward()` to `resultForwardAction()` to stick to Symfony naming standards. This fixes the naming and declaration conflict.

```
/**
 * @Route("/forwarding", name="forwarding")
 */
public function forwardAction() 
{
    $response = $this->forward(
        'App\Controller\DefaultController::resultForward',
        array('param' => 1)
    );
    return $response;
}

/**
 * @Route("/resultatForwarding/{param}", name="resultforward")
 */
public function resultForwardAction($param) 
{
    exit('Voila la page à qui j\'a forwardé et voil son param' . $param);
}
```

And a bit of hint for code style, it can be useful to check to PSR-1 and PSR-2 coding recommendations. Of course it's always matter of taste, but it's useful to get used to generally accepted standards, so other people can read your code more easily.

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/